# Temporarily disabling all SSL certificates on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm writing a PHP client library for an API, and want to include the SSL certificate as part of the library (because many people are still running code on outdated servers, which might not have our SSL certificate).

To test this out I'd like to temporarily disable the checks using the certificates that ship with Mac OS X, by doing something like temporarily moving the folder containing all of the system certificates to a different location.

Where does this folder live, and will this even work?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is probably export everything from Keychain in System Preferences, and import when finished